# VOD streaming is too slow

Tags: vlc

I am trying out VOD streaming with latest VLC as described in this wiki:
https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/VLM/ and trying to stream an HD movie file with extension mp4. 
i am able to open the stream in VLC running on the same machine, but it takes lot of time to even start playing back. (minutes). The test is run in Fedora 20.

My machine is capable enough to play HD video.

I have tried with and with trans-coding and results are same.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue and it is strange.

I had the streaming server and client in the same machine. The streaming was always extremely slow. However, disconnecting from the network made it work fast..  It did not matter whether the network connection was wifi or ethernet.
However, if you were to run the client in a different machine, it work properly.